# Count uid from two tables who look the same sort by tablename

Tags: sql, select, count

since I am not as good with more complex SQL SELECT Statements I thought of just asking here, since it's hard to find something right on topic.

I got two tables who have exactly the same structure like

```
TABLE A (id (INT(11)), time (VARCHAR(10));)
TABLE B (id (INT(11)), time (VARCHAR(10));)
```

Now I want a single SELECT to count the entrys of an specific id in both tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE A WHERE id = '1';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE B WHERE id = '1';
```

So I thought it would be much better for the database performance if I use one SELECT instead of one.

Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count, 'tableA' as table_name FROM TABLEA WHERE id = '1'
union all
SELECT COUNT(*), 'tableB' FROM TABLEB WHERE id = '1'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the separate counts in a single row, you can use subqueries

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE A WHERE id = '1') a_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE B WHERE id = '1') b_count;
```

Comment: this solution is still the same perfomance as I would do it in 2 SELECT ... cause you still do it in two SELECTS kinda.
It's double the amount of time I use for "juergen d"'s solution

Comment: @Kris both the `union all` version and this query have nearly identical query plans and take the same amount of time

Comment: I am sorry - my debugger messed it up :( - youre right. I thought there could be a better version of just using SELECTs in SELECT - but somehow it doesn't seems like it

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like:

```
select count(*) 
from (
    select id from t1 where id = 1
    union all
    select id from t2 where id = 1
) as t
```

Another alternative is:

```
select sum(cnt) 
from (
    select count(*) as cnt from t1 where id = 1
    union all
    select count(*) as cnt from t2 where id = 1
) as t
```

Comment: They both give me a SUM from both counts. I wanna get their value seperately